# Do I need always close connection with db before return some value from function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Do I need always close connection with db before return some value from function if I work with db within this function?

Yes, I'm using connection internally in function.

Comment: It depends on whether you opened this connection in this function only for internal (function's) use or you use this connection globally for entire application. Posting your code example could help to get a correct answer for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There's very rarely a need to close a DB connection until you're actually done using it. Usually you don't even have to disconnect anyways, as PHP will do that automatically as part of the script's shutdown/cleanup routines.

Doing a connect-query->disconnect cycle repeatedly in your code is highly wasteful. The connect/disconnect sequences are just a waste of CPU cycles and memory resources. Connect once at the beginning, do however many DB operations are needed, then... just ignore the connection. PHP will handle the cleanup at the end.

About the only time you would want to force a disconnect is if your script is long-running, and you don't need the DB for the duration of that "long" section. Freeing up the DB connection may be useful in that case, but only if you have "many" other DB-using operations occurring in other parallel scripts. There's no point in holding a connection slot open and then not using it.

Similarly, you generally only ever need one database connection in your script, UNLESS you need to connect with different credentials to perform some sensitive operation, or have to connect to two or more completely separate DB engines.

Comment: So creating connection within function is a bad practice? It's better to pass pdo object to a function?

Comment: no. it's not bad. but it'd be bad if you had `function used_a_lot() { connect_to_db(); do_something; disconnect(); }`